# Android: viewpager swipe has a strange behavior with the fragment items

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a standard Viewpager with Tab. In each page there is a standard Fragment which contains a RecyclerView (items in this list are in blue):

[image]

So when I swipe in the viewpager, from a gesture into an item in the list, the swipe works and **a click is done automatically**, when I remove my finger, on the item list (so a new Activity starts; because when I click normally on an item list I start a new Activity).

So how can I disable the childs event during a swipe on the viewpager?